# Can you create an Azure Functions from Visual Studio Mac?

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-functions, visual-studio-mac

I don't see the option to create an Azure function class library template in new projects under Visual Studio Mac.  If I created one manually - what files do I need to include and what framework target should I use for the library?  .net core or .net standard or something custom?

Alternatively - if I use a CSX script file instead, how would I debug that on a mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Functions support for Visual Studio for Mac is available in the alpha channel, so you need to switch to that in order to use this functionality.

The tooling there is similar to what is available for Visual Studio 2015, supporting CSX based projects (as opposed to pre-compiled, class library projects) and giving you a local run/debug experience.

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to use it from the alpha channel?

Comment: This should cover the topic: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/#visualstudiomac

Comment: Thanks for the link. I already switched over the alpha channel and created my project, but I couldn't figure out how to do anything else. I have experience building function apps in visual studio (win).

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Mac 7.2 this feature was moved into an extension. Just open the extension manager - search for "functions" and you can install that feature again.